# In CF, can I call a custom tag using a variable for its name?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I would like to call a custom tag using a variable in it's name. Like this

```
<cfset slist = 'product_categories'>
<cf_cu_show_#slist#>
```

This gives me an error on the #. The custom tag cu_show_product_categories is present and working when I call it the conventional way.
The idea is to build a list to loop through, calling several custom tags.

```
<cfset slist = 'product_categories'>
<cfif a = 'blogs'>
    <cfset slist = listAppend(slist,"blogs")>
</cfif>
<cfif b = 'posts'> 
    <cfset s_list = listAppend(slist,"last_posts")>
</cfif>
<cfloop list="#slist#" index="i">
    <cf_cu_show_#i#>
</cfloop>
```

I tried to google, but cannot find anything useful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In order to call the custom tag using a variable name, you would have to call it using the `<cfmodule>` syntax instead.  While `<cf_cu_show_#slist#>` is invalid (as you discovered), you would call it instead with `<cfmodule template="cu_show_#slist#.cfm">` in order to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Your overall approach seems pretty labour instensive.  Instead of having several custom tags, having one, which can take a variety of input parameters, seems like a way to get the job done with less code.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk, thank you for your advice. The example given by me is a very simplified piece of code. Reality is that 9 environments make use of the custom tags, each with different conditions and also with different displaying orders. For readabilty purposes I chose this approach so we have the sections in different custom tags and do not need to call it with a ton of variables. Also, I found it difficult to build 1 custom tag in which I need to decide which sections in a specific order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you already discovered, using a variable name in calling the custom tag is invalid.  The way around this is to call the custom tag using the `<cfmodule>` syntax instead.  In your first scenario, you would call it like this.

```
<cfset slist = 'product_categories'>
<cfmodule template="cu_show_#slist#.cfm">
```

In the lower example, you would modify your code as such.

```
<cfset slist = 'product_categories'>
<cfif a = 'blogs'>
    <cfset slist = listAppend(slist,"blogs")>
</cfif>
<cfif b = 'posts'> 
    <cfset s_list = listAppend(slist,"last_posts")>
</cfif>
<cfloop list="#slist#" index="i">
    <cfmodule template="cu_show_#i#.cfm">
</cfloop>
```

Here's the documentation link on how to use `<cfmodule>`.
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfmodule.html

I also found another decent link where they demonstrate your scenario in which you need to supply the tag name dynamically as seen here at https://flylib.com/books/en/2.375.1.420/1/

Comment: It’s important to note, and I think this answer should be edited to reflect this, that a custom tag is typically called twice, once at the start (thisTag.executionMode == “start”), and once at the end (thisTag.executionMode == “end”). When you use cfmodule to call a custom tag, it is only called once, at the start.

Comment: In both <cf_> syntax and <cfmodule> syntax, the custom tag is only called a second time if the tag is closed. This can be done by adding "/" before the ">" of the tag or by having a closing tag. The use of cfmodule doesn't change the fundamental nature of how this works.

Comment: Pentesters love to complain when there is a dynamic part in the name of a file that is included/executed. Take care you don't pass a URL or FORM variable as file name.

Comment: Thank you very much user12031119, this works like a charm. Now I noticed that, my file being a custom tag, both <cfmodule template="cu_show_#i#.cfm"> and <cfmodule name="cu_show_#i#"> work. Is there a significant difference between both ways that I need to take into account?

Comment: @Redtopia And Steve Bryant: Both very excellent points. `cfmodule` is one of those things that can really give you odd behavior if you don't use `thisTag.executionMode` and you close it.

Comment: @SteveBryant, my apologies, you are correct assuming the call is made in tag mode. However the behavior is different when calling cfmodule in cfscript because there is no way to “end” the tag.

Comment: @Veni The reason why the `template` and `name` attributes both work identically in your scenario is because you're not specifying a file path to the custom tag.  However, if you did need to specify a file path, the usage becomes different.  For a more complete explanation, see here at https://cfdocs.org/cfmodule